# node.js Internals: How can I find out where `process.binding('eval')` gets defined?

Tags: c++, node.js, v8, libuv

- How can I find out where in the C++ source code of node.js the JavaScript object gets defined which I can access through `process.binding('eval')`? - I already found out that it's in `/src/node_script.cc` in this special case, but: How can I know where I can **find** that module just when I just **take a look on the `/src/` directory overview**? I don't want to step through all the files in `/src/` in order to look for a module.
- Where can I find some deep going information about the internals of `process.binding()`s?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I was looking for the same myself today. I cannot guarantee that there isn't more to it, but this is what I discovered.

src/node_extensions.h contains a list of built-in modules, defined like:

```
ITEM(node_module_name)
```

where module_name is the name of the module (obviously)

You can find out which file defines that module by searching for which file has a line that starts with

```
NODE_MODULE(node_module_name,
```

So, to find the file that defines the 'evals' module for process.bindings:

```
$ grep "NODE_MODULE(node_evals" src/*.cc
src/node_script.cc:NODE_MODULE(node_evals, node::InitEvals)
```