# Nodejs: How to locate source file of process.binding()?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, electron, v8

I am trying to find the location of the source file for an internal module called by process.binding('base_filter') in "base-filter.js". 
It's a react/electron app using electron-prebuilt.

This script is located in:

```
    +-- electron-prebuilt
    |   +-- dist
    |       +-- resources
    |           +-- electron.asar
    |               +-- filtering
    |                   +-- api
    |                       +-- exports
    |                           +-- base-filter.js
```

I've searched exhaustively for solutions, I've tried:

```
    var natives = process.binding('natives');
    for (var key in natives) {
        console.log(key);
    }
```

From [How to obtain a list of all available Node.js modules?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35725976/how-to-obtain-a-list-of-all-available-node-js-modules)

Which didn't show the module.

I've tried:

[node.js Internals: How can I find out where `process.binding('eval')` gets defined?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12138851/node-js-internals-how-can-i-find-out-where-process-bindingeval-gets-defin)

[What is `process.binding('fs')` in `fs.js`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37916949/what-is-process-bindingfs-in-fs-js)

I've tried batch searching every single file in the code-base for mention of "base_filter" with no success, i also tried searching my PCs appdata and user files thinking it might be caching somewhere, no success.

I'm wringing my hair out over this, I just need to be able to trace where it's being loaded from so i can edit it/ fix any problems.

I would appreciate any help, thank you.